# Alpine: work with some e-mails

Tags: linux, email, smtp, alpine-mail

How can I setup alpine to use more than one mail address? That `SMTP Server` parameter in `config` looks like an global. Can someone help me? 
NOTE: At least for both e-mails on the same server. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Setup > collectionLists** add a new entry like below:
(at the main menu just press `S L A`):

here an example if you have a gmail account:

```
Nickname  : gmail-test
Server    : imap.gmail.com/ssl/user=your_user_name@gmail.com
Path      :
View      :
```

The corresponding entry (gmail-test in this example) will be created and will be accessible at `Folder List`.

Then create a role something like below (by pressing `S R R A` at the main menu). At the moment you compose a new message, Alpine ask you to select your created smtp's. You can several roles and you can use several smtp's.

```
Nickname = gmail-test
Comment = <No Value Set>
==================================== CURRENT FOLDER CONDITIONS BEGIN HERE ==============
=======================
Current Folder Type = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
( ) Any
( ) News
(*) Email
( ) Specific (Enter Incoming Nicknames or use ^T)
Folder List = {imap.gmail.com/ssl/user=your_user_name@gmail.com}INBOX
==================================== CURRENT MESSAGE CONDITIONS BEGIN HERE =============
=======================
To pattern = your_user_name@gmail.com
From pattern = <No Value Set>
Sender pattern = <No Value Set>
Cc pattern = <No Value Set>
News pattern = <No Value Set>
Subject pattern = <No Value Set>
Recip pattern = <No Value Set>
Partic pattern = <No Value Set>
Add Extra Headers
AllText pattern = <No Value Set>
BdyText pattern = <No Value Set>
Age interval = <No Value Set>
Size interval = <No Value Set>
Score interval = <No Value Set>
Keyword pattern = <No Value Set>
Charset pattern = <No Value Set>
Message is Important? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Message is New (Unseen)? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Message is Recent? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Message is Deleted? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Message is Answered? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Subject contains raw 8-bit? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Beginning of Month? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Beginning of Year? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes
( ) No
Address in address book? = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
(*) Don't care, always matches
( ) Yes, in any address book
( ) No, not in any address book
( ) Yes, in specific address books
( ) No, not in any of specific address books
Abook List = <No Value Set>
Types of addresses to check for in address book = Set Address types
--- --------------------
[X] From
[X] Reply-To
[ ] Sender
[ ] To
[ ] Cc
External Categorizer Commands = Command = <No Value Set>
Exit Status Interval = <No Value Set>
Character Limit = <No Value Set: using "-1">
============================================= ACTIONS BEGIN HERE =======================
=======================
Initialize settings using role : <No Value Set>
Set From = your_user_name@gmail.com
Set Reply-To = <No Value Set>
Set Fcc = {imap.gmail.com/ssl/user=your_user_name@gmail.com}sent
Set LiteralSig = <No Value Set>
Set Signature = <Ignored: using LiteralSig instead>
Set Template = <No Value Set>
Set Other Hdrs = <No Value Set>
Use SMTP Server = smtp.gmail.com/ssl/user=your_user_name@gmail.com
Use NNTP Server = <No Value Set>
============================================= OPTIONS BEGIN HERE =======================
=======================
Features = Set Feature Name
--- --------------------
[ ] use-date-header-for-age
=============================================== USES BEGIN HERE ========================
=======================
Reply Use = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
( ) Never
( ) With confirmation
(*) Without confirmation
Forward Use = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
( ) Never
(*) With confirmation
( ) Without confirmation
Compose Use = Set Choose One
--- --------------------
( ) Never
(*) With confirmation
( ) Without confirmation
```

Comment: What's about SMTP server? There are only one for all.